# Want to make info collapse on hover

Tags: jquery, html

I am a beginner at HTML and was wondering if you could tell me how to add a hover thing to my code:

```
<div class="container text-center" style="padding-top: 70px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p class="text-center"><strong>Corvo Attano</strong></p><br>
            <a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">
                <img src="images/corvo.jpg" class="img-circle person" alt="Random Name" width="200" height="200">
            </a>
            <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                <p>Dishonored 1, Dishonored 2, Brigmore Witches</p>
                <p>Bears the Outsider's Mark</p>
                <p>Father of Emily Kaldwin</p>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

The look of the HTML is pictures of characters. Right now, I have it so that when you click on the picture, #demo appears below. I was wondering if you could help me figure out how to make it display when I hover my mouse, and dissapear when my mouse moves away. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using standard JavaScript, there is the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attribute.
Use them like this:

```
<img src="..." onmouseover="showPic()" onmouseover="hidePic()" />
<script>function showPic(){...} function hidePic(){...}</script>
```

When you have jQuery you can also make use of the `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` functions.

However, you are using the Collapse library in Bootstrap, which means you have a function like the functions `showPic` and `hidePic` already.
The `data-toggle:collapse` is basically the same as calling `.collapse()` on the object, according to [the documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp).
So to achieve what you're trying to achieve, the following should work:

```
<a href="#demo" onmouseover="$('#demo').collapse('show')" onmouseout="$('#demo').collapse('hide')"> ... </a>
```

Comment: Is that to show the picture though? Because I was trying to find out how to make the paragraphs show under the picture. http://webdesign.eastsideprep.org/~spedersen/client1/char.html

If you click on one of the pictures, the paragraph shows, then hides when you click again. I want to see if I can make the paragraph show when you move your mouse over, and hide when you move your mouse away.

Comment: My apologies, I've not taken into account the Bootstrap side of things. But I have edited my answer to include the bootstrap libraries. Please go ahead and give it a try, and tell me if that worked for you.